# Opening a remote URL

Tags: android, cordova

What I am trying to do is creating an Android application using PhoneGap. All it does when launched is opening a specific URL at my website.

There will be no local HTML/CSS/JS.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: paste your code. what you have tried?

Comment: @praveenSharma What I tried is creating the basic PhoneGap app then I deleted their HTML body and placed a "full screen" iframe but that doesn't seem right.

Comment: see you can open remote url on your MainActivty java class. I post answer have a look on it and let me know if you have still problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your MainActivity class you can achieve this as

```
super.loadUrl("http://www.yourwebsite.com/test1.html");
```

make sure you must have permission for internet.

Comment: Are you referring to my-app/platforms/android/CordovaLib/CordovaActivity.java? If so, the file is 1224 line long. Where do I put the code you mentioned exactly?

Comment: No in your application project there is src folder. In that folder there must be a java class file.